# how to change the character limit when read a cell from excel sheet in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a cell value from the excel.

Problem is, it is reading only first 255 characters from a particular cell.
How can I increase the limit of character reading in perl?

```
INPUT at xls (row, column) (0,0) = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

OUTPUT:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2


use strict;use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $xls_name = $ARGV[0]; my $PARAM_SHEET = $ARGV[1];
my $param_sheet = $excel->Worksheet($PARAM_SHEET);
my $FILE = "$xls_name";
my $pin_value ;my $pin;
my $excel = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook->Parse($FILE);
$pin            = $param_sheet->Cell(0,0);
$pin_value      = ($pin->Value());
$pin_value      =~ s/\s+$//;
print "$pin_value\n";
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You are not declaring `$param` or `$cust_name`, and you are not telling us what those values are, or what's in the cell. Please [edit] your question and show your _real code_, as well as the data you are working with.

Comment: Hi Simbabque, I have updated the code and provided the corresponding inputs/outputs. Please suggest how to read whole data from a cell at once.

Comment: Which version of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel are you using, and what version of Excel file do you have? In the latest S::PE there is no method `Value`. All the methods are lower case, so y our code would not work. There could be a limitation on the number of characters a cell can store. Or it could be that the format of the cell boggles up the value. Try `$cell->unformatted` instead and see if that gives you a longer string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you aren't saving it correctly?  The following is pulled from the synopsis of `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel v2.40` and `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel v0.65` and it handles large values without any problem:

**write_huge.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

# Create a new Excel workbook
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls');

# Add a worksheet
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

#  Add and define a format
my $format = $workbook->add_format(); # Add a format
$format->set_bold();
$format->set_color('red');
$format->set_align('center');

# Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
my ($row,$col) = (0,0);
my $huge = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\n"x30;
$worksheet->write($row, $col, $huge, $format);
$worksheet->write(1,    $col, $huge);
```

**read_huge.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('perl.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
perl write_huge.pl
perl read_huge.pl

Row, Col    = (0, 0)
Value       = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Unformatted = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9


Row, Col    = (1, 0)
Value       = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Unformatted = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out this was an issue due to [compatibility mode].
Thanks for suggestions